# expected a spy but got undefined?

Tags: angularjs, tdd, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spy

Trying to get my head around jasmine spies, this is what my test looks like:

```
  $scope.switchTurns = function () {
    $scope.playerTurn = !$scope.playerTurn;
    console.log($scope.centrePileCards.length);
    if ($scope.playerTurn == 1) {
      $scope.pickCard();
    }
  }
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
it('should pick one card',function(){
    var controller = createController();
    spyOn(scope,'pickCard')
    scope.switchTurns();
    scope.playerTurn=1;
    expect(scope.pickCard()).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
```

I am getting this error now:

```
Error : Expected a spy , but got undefined.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: you should accept zucker's answer.  Instafix with a nice explanation

Answer (score 34):

`scope.pickCard()` is result of method. In your case it is `undefined`.
When you are using `spyOn` you should write:

`expect(scope.pickCard).toHaveBeenCalled();`